# Resources like images and securing them

Tags: web-services, security, oauth, webserver

I've been thinking about this off and on and did a quick test with Facebook. Assume you have a Facebook like site and strip it down to images and profiles. Images you choose to either share with friends or not to. Obviously in the DB there are values applied on the meta-data if it is shared or not, with whom it is shared, ect.

Now say I view a particular image, so I now have an HTTPS URL for that resource (an image in this example). At that point, the resource can be viewed without logging in or having a token of any sort. You have the URL, load it into any browser and you see that resource. Granted, it is provided in an SSL layer and they have fairly long, complex names, but I can view it without authenticating.

I can't help but think, is this the best that can be done? Can this type of content be secured so if you have a direct URL you cannot load it? What about files that may be more sensitive? If someone has a path can they forever now access that resource? Can OAuth be of any help in this case?

I guess I'm just thinking out loud about how these resources can be secured, so that if I hit a URL directly I will not always get that resource without being authenticated. Is there another process or method that I may be missing? If so what is the right balance between performance and security and what are the trade-offs? Would like to look into options that are scalable.

Comment: Voting this question down is kind of silly.

Comment: Another vote down? Really. Maybe people should actually comment or add to this post. Funny I thought stack overflow was for sharing ideas...

Comment: Agreed.  If you're voting this down, please leave a comment as to why.  IMO there's nothing wrong with this question.  Security is important for software development and this is completely on topic.

Comment: +1 for a good question that generated good conversation and exposed problematic security holes in prominent web applications

Answer (score 2):

In resource access implementations you describe this would be considered a vulnerability.  Almost every web app has control to ensure that requested resources are only delivered to an authenticated and authorized user.  The only time when this would not be the case would be with a simple server that does no session tracking.  It is very sad that Facebook or any reputable website is vulnerable to this in 2013.  This is a vulnerability that I saw a lot in the '90s and early 2000s.

Most web applications maintain state of the user's session in some form.  When a resource is requested (such as an image by URL), the session token (or other method) is checked to ensure that the user is authenticated, and that the user is authorized to request that resource (access controls) before it is returned.  If the user doesn't check, the request is denied.

Comment: If you have the url of a resource on facebook you can view it no matter what the permissions are and even if you are not authenticated. To test it yourself upload a image and set it viewable to you only. Open up developer tools in chrome and go to the network tab. You can then view the URL of the requested resource. Log out of facebook, clear cache or open a browser that you have never authenticated facebook with. You will be able to view that image. So the above question and comments still stand. Do you have a way of securing a resource which you already know the URL of? In this case an image

Comment: @Michael I believe you about Facebook being vulnerable, but what I said still stands.  This is a vulnerability that is not common.  It shocks me that Facebook is vulnerable, but I can assure you this is not common.  You have to understand how servers/web apps work.  Just because a resource is requested does not mean it is returned.  An HTTP request comes through and is passed to the web app.  The web app can respond with whatever it wants, nothing forces it to return the requested resource.  In ASP.NET I check the Session ID of the requester against my HashMap of authenticated users.

Comment: After authentication, I then check the ACL for the resource to see if the user is authorized.  If both of these check, then I return the resource as requested.  If something isn't right, I return an HTTP 403 Forbidden.

Comment: On your Facebook checks, make sure the resource you are requesting isn't public permission.  Facebook allows some resources to be publicly accessed, and of course these wouldn't be subject to access controls.  Try to access an image of somebody who has their stuff set to private.  Make sure it's not a profile picture.

Comment: I think you are not fully understanding my question. I do understand how webapps work. What I am asking is once the webapp has decided you are authorized to view the requested resource it needs to pass you a URL (in facebooks case) to that resource. My question is around how you protect that URL to the resource. The only way I could see something like images being secure comes with performance hits like storing the binary data in the DB, or having a web service respond not with a URL but the binary data. Do you have an example of how the URL could be passed but still secure?

Comment: I do think we're mis-communicating.  A URL is nothing more than a way to identify a resource that exists somewhere.  Simply having a URL does not mean that the owner of that resource must send it to you.  Here's an example.  I have an account on DigitalBlasphemy.com, so I can access the "members only" images when I'm logged in.  This URL works fine for me if I'm logged in, but *the same* URL does not work if I'm not logged in.  Check it out:  http://digitalblasphemy.com/content/png/pulsar2k1022880.png

Comment: I'm assuming that if you are a member at all you would be able to access this image? Essentially they have password protected that folder and are only checking if you are logged in? I would be looking for something with finer grain control. Something like the facebook kind of model. Friends can see this resource, it is private, ect. I know tomcat for instance can refer to a db for authentication. But looking for something that plays nice with OAuth and bearer tokens potentially.

Comment: I can't access Facebook from work, but I'll try your link when I get home and let you know.  Yes you're correct that any member can access that image.

Comment: If you have any thoughts on fine grain control with a URL resource feel free to share. I'm going to do some more research on this as see what I can find out. I'll post what I find here. Seems like there should be some sort of solution other than going the binary route.

Comment: This looks along the lines of what I was looking for: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth

Comment: @Michael Do you know where the Facebook link went?  I was going to give it a shot but I don't see it

Comment: I ended up removing it. Can post again if you are interested. I found something else pretty interesting. Instagram is even worse of protecting their images. They don;t even transfer their images over a SSL connection. Just wide open http URL's. Again it's not like this is super confidential files we are dealing with, but interesting for sure.

Comment: @Michael That is really interesting about Instagram. Perhaps this vulnerability is (scarily) not as widely recognized as I thought.  BTW thanks for the good conversation. I just reread this exchange and I feel that I may have come off as rude/condescending towards you. I truly didn't mean to, and I apologize. This has been an interesting exchange and I feel more enlightened because of it

Comment: I didn't take it that way at all so no worries :). It seems things are pretty wide open. My thoughts are because of the type of content, decisions were made not to have extra resources (hardware and development time) on securing them any further. If you do a bit of digging there is an incredible amount of un-secure data out there. More security by obscurity.

Comment: @Michael Glad to hear :)  I think you're right about security suffering from people not wanting to put resources into it. I just heard someone the other day say "We don't need to worry about security, because this system will be on a closed net."  Unfortunately he's not the only one in the org that feels that way.  \*sigh\*

Comment: I hear that, I've been there. Maybe thats why there was votes down :).